# How to use Entity Framework 4 against system views on SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-4

I'm a newbie to Entity Framework, so I'd like to try something simple to get started on Visual Studio 2010.

Suppose I start out with the following SQL statement (the View sys.databases exists in the master database on SQL Azure):

```
SELECT name, create_date
  FROM sys.databases
 WHERE database_id > 3
```

So instead of using traditional ADO.NET of executing this SQL and using a DataReader to insert the results into a custom class, I attempt doing things the EF way.

So I attempted to create a Entity Data Model.  In the Wizard, I am given two choices: "Generate from Database" or "Empty Model".  I tried to "Generate from Database", but the Wizard doesn't list the vast majority of the Views in the master database.  So that approach appears to be a dead-end.  I then tried "Empty Model", which is a bit more work (for this newbie) and insists on prefixing "databases" with "dbo", and I need "sys". So I'm basically stuck, and I haven't found any examples of people using EF to work with system views.

Does anyone have any detailed examples of accomplishing this?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new view which which returns the system view that you want, and then use that in your EDMX design.

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SysDatabasesView] AS SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

then use your `SysDatabasesView` instead of `sys.databases`.

Comment: That is a clever solution for User Databases, but I don't want to (or should I say not allowed to) create a View on the Master database, which is where sys.databases is located.  I'll give you credit for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if the goal is to use EF datacontext, create a complex type 'DB' in EF that contain name and create_date.

Issue the query directly using ExecuteStoreQuery

```
static readonly String dbCommand = @"select [name],create_date from sys.databases where id > 0";
context.ExecuteStoreQuery<DB>(dbCommand);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... You just need to add Master DB on EDMX and import the system view sys.databases.